# Contra Rebirth Wii on Dolphin: can't move when shooting

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, emulation, dolphin-emulator, contra-rebirth

I run Contra Rebirth WiiWare at Dolphin Emulator for Ubuntu. I'm using Logitech Rumblepad2 that I use to emulate Wiimote. And I can't run when I'm shooting. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro it was an artillery mode :-D

Comment: So were you able to fix the issue? If you did fix it, can you add how you fixed it as an answer?